# Autofitting excel columns with a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with many columns: Symptoms, Dates, issues and etc. I used autofitting, so that the dates would be visible, otherwise it printed this #####. But after autofitting my Symptom column got very long(its length is equal to 255). I wanted to check if my column value's length is greater than 150, it would autofit with the length of column name. I implemented the code below but it doesn't do what I want. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?
[image]

```
df = pd.read_excel('merged.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("output.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter")
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1',  index=False)
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

for col_num, value in enumerate(df.columns.values):
    worksheet.write(0, col_num, value, header_format)

    column_len = df[value].astype(str).str.len().max()
    if column_len > 150:
        column_len = len(value) 
    else:
        column_len = max(column_len, len(value))

    
    worksheet.set_column(col_num, col_num, column_len)

writer.save()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please support your question with data because we do not know what the type of columns is and how do you want your data to fit in excel?

Comment: Please add a sample input, output and what is not working to the question. Adding images are not the best way to ask question as it make it hard to read and replicate the scenario.

Comment: What was the error you got? you did not get the right output?

Comment: I get the same output with the same length of Symptom column, nothing changed, no error

Comment: I suggest only autofit the date column and do not autofit other columns unless you want to autofit all columns.

Comment: besides date column, tehre are others columns as well that need autofitting

Comment: I almost finished the answer and I would like to post it but I would like to make sure that in your column 'Symptom' which length is 7 and the data length is greater than 150, in this case, and based on your code, the column length should be the same width of your data which is greater than 150, but this is not good fitting, am I right?

Comment: yes, it takes a lot of space in the excel file and is not readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this, do not forget to add `dtype` when you read from excel:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('merged.xlsx',dtype=str)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("output.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter")
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1',  index=False)
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

for column in df:
    value = df[column].astype(str).map(len).max()

    if value > 50:   
        column_width = len(column)
    else:
        column_width = max(value, len(column))
        
    col_idx = df.columns.get_loc(column)
    worksheet.set_column(col_idx, col_idx, column_width)
    
writer.save()
```

I prefer to make the value > 50 and you can adjust it.

**Before autofitting:**
[image]

**After autofitting:**

[image]